# How can I get the equation solution in the form of y1/y2

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have some trouble getting the equation solution in the variable fraction form.
If there is an equation set shows below:
[image]

```
ug == Lg D[ig[t], t] + uc
ig == i + Cf D[uc[t], t]
uc == L D[i[t], t] + uab
Sab*i == Cd D[Udc[t], t] + Udc/RL
uab == Sab Uab
```

How can I get the solution of ig/uab[image]

Comment: In the code, the dependence on `t` must be explicit for all variables. The last equation in your code does not agree with the written equations. There are six variables but only five equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, Lg, Cf, L, Cd, Sab, RL are constants and Udc, i are known functions of t. Then:

```
Clear[ug, ig, uc, uab, Udc, RL, Sab]
ug[t_] = Lg D[ig[t], t] + uc[t];
ig[t_] = i[t] + Cf D[uc[t], t];
uc[t_] = L D[i[t], t] + uab[t];
i[t_] = (Cd D[Udc[t], t] + Udc[t]/RL)/Sab;
uab[t_] = Sab Udc[t];
```

And:

```
ig[t]/uab[t]  // Simplify
```

[image]